# Typescript Select Ids from object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am new to Typescript. I want to select ids from observable

This is my observable

```
let myObj = [{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "Mary"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "text": "Nancy"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "text": "Paul"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "text": "Cheryl"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "text": "Frances"
}]
```

Expected Result :

```
let selectedIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Can I do this without creating an array and pushing the ids in a for loop.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array

Comment: Also you *start* with an array. `myObj.map(thing => thing.id)` would suffice.

Comment: Yes **map**  will do the things thanks Jonathan and jonrshare

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `Array#map` to map one array to another:

```js
const myObj = [{"id":1,"text":"Mary"},{"id":2,"text":"Nancy"},{"id":3,"text":"Paul"},{"id":4,"text":"Cheryl"},{"id":5,"text":"Frances"}];

const selectedIds = myObj.map(({ id }) => id);

console.log(selectedIds);
```

Comment: We can make type script like too  "myObj.map(p=>p.id)"

Answer (score -9):

```
<script>
      ..........Your Ajax / JSON  Request Sending Code

      function success(response)
      {
            var arr = JSON.parse(response);

            var selectedIds  = new Array();

            for(var i=0;i < arr.length ; i++)
            {
                  selectedIds["[" + arr[i].id + "]"] ; 
            }
            document.write(selectedIds);
      }

</script>
```

Comment: Try and provide an explanation along with the code snippet. It helps us understand your reasoning behind including the snippet. Additionally, the OP is specifically asking for a method of achieving this without looping through each item in the Array.