# Javascript Merge multiple object values into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
[ { Id:1, Name:'' }, { Id:2, Name:'' }, { Id:2, Name:'' } ]
```

I want a result object that looks like this:

```
{ Id:[1, 2, 3] }
```

How do I achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865) and [Returning only certain properties from an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440403) and [Typescript Select Ids from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197546)

Comment: @adiga I searched and looked up multiple posts, but apparently I didn't know how to phrase my question so I didn't find the answer to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an [Object Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get ids array to fulfill the `Id` property.

Code:

```js
const data = [ { Id: 1, Name:'' }, { Id: 2, Name:'' }, { Id: 3, Name:'' } ]
const result = { Id: data.map(obj => obj.Id) };

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const array = [ { Id:1, Name:'' }, { Id:2, Name:'' }, { Id:2, Name:'' } ];
console.log({Id: array.map(element => element.Id)})
```